# Calculating AUC for a glm model on data imputed using the MICE package

Tags: r, glm, roc, auc, r-mice

On a regular dataset, the calls will go like this:

```
library(ROCR)

mymodelFit1 <- glm(data = myData, Outcome~ predictor1+ 
predictor2+ predictor3,
             family = binomial(link = "logit")))

prob <- predict(mymodelFit1, newdata=myData, type="response")
pred <- prediction(prob, myData$Outcome)
perf <- performance(pred, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")
plot(perf)
auc <- performance(pred, measure = "auc")
auc <- auc@y.values[[1]]
auc
```

Now, I have used the mice package to impute missing data:

```
library(mice)

impData <- mice(analysis_set,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',
seed=500, printFlag = FALSE)
```

And generated a logistic model using the imputed dataset:

```
mymodelFit2 <- with(data = impData, exp = glm(Outcome~ predictor1+ 
predictor2 + predictor3,
             family = binomial(link = "logit")))
```

**The question is:** how can I calculate the AUC for the new model (mymodelFit2)?

"mice" generates x number of sets for missing values (5 in this case, specified in the m= parameter of mice()). The model has x number (5 in this case) of estimates.

Is there a function or an easy way to calculate AUC for these models? And how can I get an AUC for the **pooled model**?

Comment: I may be missing something, but you should be able to do it exactly as you did for the first model.  What error our you getting or what is your issue?

Comment: predict(mymodelFit2.. produces this message: Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('mira', 'matrix')"

Comment: You are returning an object of class mira because you are using "with()". Why don't you use as before the glm() function instead ? So the object returned will inherits from glm and can be used in the predict() function. That's basically what the error message is telling you.